# elm type alias type checking does not happen, Why does it compile?

Tags: types, elm, typechecking, type-alias

Following code has two type aliases `Name` and `Surname`.

Ideally I think this should not compile.
Why does it compile?

Does the replacement of types happen before type-checker is involved?

```
import Html

type alias Name = String
type alias Surname = String

namePrinter : Name -> Name 
namePrinter n =
  n

k : Name
k = "kaba"

j : Surname
j = "jaja"


main =
  Html.text ( "Hello!" ++ namePrinter k ++ namePrinter j )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A type alias is just that, another name for a type. It's not a different type.

You can create a distinct type by wrapping it in a custom type however:

```
type Name = Name String
type Surname = Surname String
```

But then you have to construct and deconstruct it as well:

```
namePrinter : Name -> String 
namePrinter (Name n) =
  n

k : Name
k = Name "kaba"

j : Surname
j = Surname "jaja"
```

And then this will fail to compile:

```
main =
  Html.text ( "Hello!" ++ namePrinter k ++ namePrinter j )
```

Also, if you define this type in a separate module and don't export its constructor (ie. just `Name`, instead of `Name(..)`), you have what's called an [opaque type](https://medium.com/@ckoster22/advanced-types-in-elm-opaque-types-ec5ec3b84ed2) which can be useful to enforce invariants that the type system cannot. You could for example enforce that an integer cannot be negative.

Comment: so is there something like type replacement happens for type aliases (like a preprocessor or something), before typechecking comes into picture?

Comment: I think it's easier to just think of it as an alias, i.e. multiple names that refer to the same thing, rather than thinking of it was type replacement.